# Mail.ru API - с чего начать?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mail.ru

Требуется начать изучать Mail.ru API, да и другие тоже, но начал с этого, русскоязычный и т.д. Так вот, у меня банальный вопрос, как вызвать допустим вот это ([пример](http://api.mail.ru/docs/reference/js/set-title/#example)):

```
mailru.app.utils.setTitle('Новое сообщение!');
```

и соответственно остальные, где что прописывать, как прописывать. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Как сказано в [Руководстве по использованию](http://api.mail.ru/docs/guides/jsapi/), JS API предоставляет возможность разрабатывать приложения в Моем Мире, приложения в Почте и подключать внешние сайты с использованием JavaScript. Библиотека позволяет осуществлять вызовы API прямо из браузера пользователя, минуя ваш сервер, помогая вам экономить трафик и вычислительные ресурсы. Кроме того, она дает доступ к некоторым возможностям, которые не доступны для вызова с сервера.

А по поводу, где что прописывать и как прописывать можно посмотреть в этом примере или в руководстве:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.connect.mail.ru/js/loader.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       mailru.loader.require('api', function() {
           mailru.connect.init('app_id из настроек сайта',
                               'ваш приватный ключ из настроек сайта');
           // все готово, здесь можно работать с функциями API
       });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```